# Getting emailaddress from shared mailbox in Outlook Client

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to transfer a mail from a shared mailbox with my Outlook Webaddin. I use Javascript.

I retreive the emailaddress by "const **emailAddress** = office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress"
then I put it in "fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${**emailAddress**}/messages/${emailId}/$value`," to get the mail to transfer.

On Owa it works. If I'm in my own mailbox it gives "me@domain.com", I'm in a shared mailbox it gives "shared@domain.com".

The problem is in my Outlook client. I stays on "me@domain.com" also if I'm working in a shared mailbox. So I want to get the mail from "shared@domain.com" but it search in "me@domain.com"

Have somebody a solution?

Kg,

Christophe

Comment: What Outlook client application do you use? For Windows? MacOS? Its version?

Comment: Hi, Windows, Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20526) 32-bit

Comment: This is pretty old version of the desktop application. I'd suggest updating it to the latest version first.

Comment: Hi, It's also on the new version: Microsoft® Outlook® voor Microsoft 365 MSO (Versie 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 64 bits

Comment: Try to post this as an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js

Comment: Is your issue that Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress is not returning the correct email address?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what Outlook client application is meant - Windows or MacOS. Also it would be great to know the version of that application.

Anyway, that sounds like a bug, so I'd suggest posting issues to the [Office JavaScript](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.